# How to change fragment class name tag in xml file?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-fragments, fragment

I want to change the fragment class by other fragment class.. on click event of Listview

Answer (score 3):

> How to change fragment class name tag in xml file?

You open up your editor and type in a new value.

> I want to change the fragment class by other fragment class.. on click event of Listview

You remove the `<fragment>` from the XML file and handle your fragment initialization and on-click changes via `FragmentTransactions`. `<fragment>` is only used for fragments that will not be changing during the lifetime of the activity.